# Register autofac in windows service project

Tags: c#, .net, service, autofac

I want to use autofac in my project for windows service but I get this error:

"The requested service 'InsideView.Business.Services.BusinessServiceFactory' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency."

My code:

```
       var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

       foreach (var type in typeof(IMyService).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service") && type.IsClass))
        {
            var siblingInterface = type.GetInterfaces().First(i => i.Name == "I" + type.Name);
            builder.RegisterType(type).Keyed(siblingInterface, typeof(IBusinessService)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }

        builder.RegisterType<BusinessServiceFactory>()
            .As<IBusinessServiceFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();


        IContainer container = builder.Build();

       var businessFactory = container.Resolve<BusinessServiceFactory>()
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have registered the service as `IBusinessServiceFactory` you must also resolve for `IBusinessServiceFactory`, not the class type `BusinessServiceFactory` as you are doing in the sample.